# Android schedule every 5 second work only once at time

Tags: android

in Android application i would like to show simple message in `Logcat` or show simple notification, my implemented `Alarm Manager` work fine only once at time and stop after that and i dont show any message in `Logcat`

My Activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    scheduleNotification(getNotification("5 second delay"), 5000);
}

private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int delay) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 2000,1000 * 5,pendingIntent);
    }
}

private Notification getNotification(String content) {
    Log.e("getNotification: ", content);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification");
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
    return builder.build();
}
```

`NotificationPublisher` class:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "13789641254784001";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
        Log.e("aaa", " .......");
    }
}
```

`receiver` in android manifest

```
<receiver android:name="ir.pishguy.diabetStop.CoreApplication.Events.Broadcasts.ConnectivityReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: `AlarmManager` is not meant for intervals that short. Use a `Handler`, or `Timer`, or `ScheduledExecutorService`, etc.

Comment: @MikeM. what about 10 minute? thats not work correctly

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", "Alert");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();


    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5*1000, pendingIntent);
```